# How to sort blocks of lines with a specific line from the block?

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, regular-expression, sort

I have a file with the data like this

```
BEGIN
hello2
5
world1
END
BEGIN
hello4
2
world5
END
BEGIN
hello6
4
END
```

I want to sort the lines in the following manner based on the number inside the block. The numbers are isolated and unique.

```
BEGIN
hello4
2
world5
END
BEGIN
hello6
4
END
BEGIN
hello2
5
world1
END
```

I know how to print the blocks with sed and awk. Thats about it.

```
    # Prints the blocks including the BEGIN and END tags
    cat file | sed -n '/^BEGIN$/,/^END$/p'

    # Prints the blocks exluding the BEGIN and END tags
    awk '/^BEGIN$/ {show=1;next} /^END$/{show=0}  { print }' file
```

Comment: It would be best if you [edit]ed your question to show us what you tried.

Comment: The numbers are isolated in their lines? Are they unique?

Comment: The numbers are isolated and unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time a `BEGIN` line is encountered, separately read the next numeric line from the file using a separate handle via `getline`. Print each line from the file with two prefixes, the numeric value that was retrieved previously *and* the file record number of the current record(thus all lines within the same `BEGIN .. END` block end up with the same value in prefix 1 corresponding to the number embedded within the block). Feed this to external `sort` and `cut` utilities to handle the prefix-based sorting following by discarding the prefixes.

```
awk '/BEGIN/{"awk \\$0+0==\\$0 "FILENAME | getline x}
{print x"~"FNR"~"$0 | "sort -k1,1n -k2,2n -t~ | cut -f3- -d~"}' file
BEGIN
hello4
2
world5
END
BEGIN
hello6
4
END
BEGIN
hello2
5
world1
END
```

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk:

```
gawk '
    BEGIN { RS="\nEND\n"; ORS = RS; FS = "\n" }
    { record[$3] = $0 }
    END {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
        for (val in record) print record[val]
    }
' file
```

Based on your data, I'm assuming there's always one line between BEGIN and the number.

The `PROCINFO` line defines how the "records" array is traversed. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html

Comment: BEGIN
hello4
4
world5
END
BEGIN
hello6
5
world1
END
BEGIN
hello2
2
END

Comment: ^^ is the result. It doesn't work :(

Comment: did you use `gawk`?

Comment: @navmad `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` is a relatively recent GNU awk feature, I think: if your version of gawk doesn't support it, you should be able to achieve the same result using `asorti` i.e. by calling `asorti(record,sorted)` then `for (val in sorted) print record[sorted[val]]`

Answer (score 1):

The first line aggregates the text block, line by line, and also tries to find a number to use as a sorting critea afterwards. The if-clause `if($0+0==$0)` evaluates true when it finds a number.

The second block executes when it finds an "END" in the input, so it saves the block in an associative array, indexing it using the number found in the block.

```
awk '{block=block"\n"$0; if($0+0==$0) num=$0;} 
/^END$/ {blks[num]=block; block=""} 
END {for(key in blks) print blks[key]}' file
```

The last line is just printing every entry of the array when it reaches the end of the input file.
Note that the associative array is already sorted (that is how it works internally), so we just need to iterate over it printing every entry.

For instance, look at the following `awk` script:

```
echo | awk '{a[2]="b"; a[1]="a"; a[3]="c"; for(key in a) print a[key];}'
```

It outputs:

```
a
b
c
```

In my answer I'm printing an extra `\n` before each block, I suppose this is not a problem. The output for your example is:

```
BEGIN
hello4
2
world5
END

BEGIN
hello6
4
END

BEGIN
hello2
5
world1
END
```

If you don't want the extra line, replace the first block of my `awk` script with:

```
{if(length(block)=="0")block=$0; else{block=block"\n"$0; if($0+0==$0) num=$0}}
```

Here is the one-liner version:

```
awk '{if(length(block)=="0")block=$0; else{block=block"\n"$0; if($0+0==$0) num=$0}} /^END$/ {blks[num]=block; block=""} END {for(key in blks) print blks[key]}' file
```

Comment: I tried your script. It doesn't sort the blocks. BEGIN
hello4
4
world5
END

BEGIN
hello6
5
END

BEGIN
hello2
2
world1
END  

^^ is the output I am getting

Comment: What is the output `awk -W version`? Also, use the one-liner at the end of my answer to make sure you are not copying it wrong.

Comment: GNU Awk 3.1.5 . I'll try again. :